# Make Zombies immune to daylight in Minecraft 1.10

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've tried googling, and I got some people saying "put a helmet on them", but for me, it doesn't work. The helmet doesn't appear. This might have something to do with how the new Minecraft scripting NBT thing works?

The command is something along the lines of:

```
/summon Zombie ~ ~ ~ {Equipment:[{},{},{},{},{id:minecraft:stone_button}]}
```

Comment: What's the command you're using to put a helmet on them?

Comment: @colorfusion something along the lines of

`/summon Zombie ~ ~ ~ {Equipment:[{},{},{},{},{id:minecraft:stone_button}]}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems with your command are:

1. In versions 1.9 and above, `Equipment` should be `ArmorItems`
2. The head slot is the 4th ArmorItems slot, rather than the 5th

The fixed command should be:

```
/summon Zombie ~ ~ ~ {ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{id:minecraft:stone_button}]}
```

Comment: Also be aware that in 1.11, all item data must include a `Count` tag with a value higher than 0.

Answer (score 0):

here's the command:

```
/summon Zombie
```

then after that, use this command:

```
/replaceitem entity @e[type=zombie] slot.armor.head minecraft:glass
```

tell me if there is any problems